# How to remove icons in the menu section which are uninstalled but still showing

Tags: 20.04, icons, gnome-shell, activities-overview

Here in this image below you can see some Microsoft office application and Dosbox icon but they are uninstalled but still it appears there.

[image: Screenshot of applications overview]

Comment: Please clarify your tags; you mention GNOME which is a desktop, but have also tagged Lubuntu which uses the LXQt desktop - so what are you using, and how do the tags relate?  (*your picture appears to be GNOME so how Lubuntu/LXQt relate is unclear*)

Comment: Whenever I click on that empty space chrome opens up. It is there like for 2-3 months

Comment: Edit your question to clarify what "*removing it through browser*" means. How? Which browser?

Comment: Hey XPRX77! Please paste the output of `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` and `lsb_release -a` in your question by [edit]ing it. BTW, please go through the [tour] page.

Comment: Also, please let us know the steps you followed to add Microsoft Office web as icon in your question by [edit]ing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to go inside this path

```
/home/user/.local/share
```

and then delete those files which says Dosbox and Microsoft (please see about what you are deleting because you also have Ms teams ).

***.local is a hidden folder so turn on the **show hidden** folder box.***

:)
XPRX77